# How to check if a string is a Google search or a URL?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsurl, google-search

I'm making a web browser that works like any other web browser.

- If you type text that is of freeform: "vasdfygvaosfh" it will do a Google search.
- If you type text that has the structure of a URL: "abc.com" it will open a new page.

What is the best approach for this problem? Should I just have a couple of if statements on whether there's a dot "." present or not?

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28079123/how-to-check-validity-of-url-in-swift) for basically the same question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this code (a category on `NSString`) to check if a string is a valid URL:

```
- (BOOL) isValidURLString
{
    BOOL result = NO;

    if (!self.length)
        return result;

    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSDataDetector *urlDetector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes: NSTextCheckingTypeLink error: &error];
    NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [urlDetector numberOfMatchesInString: self
                                                              options: 0
                                                                range: NSMakeRange(0, self.length)];

    if (!error && numberOfMatches > 0)
        result = YES;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to convert it to an NSURL anyway, and if the whole string isn't a URL, this will return true, but the conversion will fail.  It makes more sense to just see if [NSURL URLWithString:string] returns nil.  If it does, treat it as a search, else treat it as a URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a `regex` as in:

```
- (BOOL)isValidURL:(NSString *)candidate{

    NSString *urlRegEx = @"(http|https)://((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*))+";

    NSPredicate *urlTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx];

    return [urlTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
}
```