# regex for specific URLField

Tags: ios, swift, regex

I am trying to validate a form.
When validating a url field, I need to make sure, that the
user provides a string **without** `http(s)://` but may use `www.` as well as strings such as `xyz.abc.com` - note the two dots.

I tried using

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url)
```

but this applies to me having `https://` written.

Also I tried this regex from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36012850/5576110)

```
    let regEx = "((https|http)://)((\\w|-)+)(([.]|[/])((\\w|-)+))+"
```

after deleting the first part, I don't seem to get the multiple dots working.

Comment: do you want to match url like `xyz.xyz.xyz.com` or just 2 dots at most ? check this https://regex101.com/r/8PLbeU/2/ is this you want ?

Comment: @CodeManiac thanks, I am trying to match so many as user wish

Comment: any specific  domain list or any random. does the commented link serve your purpose or you have any other edge cases

Comment: @CodeManiac no, this solves it already. thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use *negative lookbehind* :

```
let regEx = "(?<!((https|http)://))((\\w|-)+)(([.]|[/])((\\w|-)+))+"
```

So given these strings :

```
let string1 = "https://www.google.com"
let string2 = "stackoverflow.com/questions/54269877/regex-for-specific-urlfield"
```

The result of evaluating them with the same predicate :

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", argumentArray:[regEx])
```

would yield the expected results :

```
predicate.evaluate(with: string1)  //false
predicate.evaluate(with: string2)  //true
```