# Array.filter with inline regex

Tags: swift, swift5

I'm writing a function that given an array of objects that contain a property called `url`, remove all objects with *bad* urls.

Here's what I have:

```
func cleanArray(data:[String: Any])->Void {
   let uris = data.filter{($0["url"] as! String).range(of: #"^(https?|file|ftp)"#, options: .regularExpression) != nil };
}
```

But xcode is showing an error in `$0`:

> Value of tuple type '(key: String, value: Any)' has no member 'subscript'

Comment: To check that a string is a valid URL, have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28079123/how-to-check-validity-of-url-in-swift/36012850

Comment: You shouldn't do URL operations like this on a raw `String`. You should extract the data from your dictionary into structs, and perform this validation in the initializer of your struct. Your code doesn't even need a regex. It would be much simpler if just used the URL API, which would allow you to write: `["http", "https", "file", "ftp"].contains(url.scheme)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[String: Any]` is a dictionary  , You need `[[String: Any]]`

```
func cleanArray(data:[[String: Any]]) -> Void { 
    let uris = data.filter{ ($0["url"] as! String).range(of: #"^(https?|file|ftp)"#, options: .regularExpression) != nil };
}
```

This could be more object oriented if you make it an array of a model