# How to check whether a String object is a link or not?

Tags: ios, swift, regex

How a string object can be validate whether it is a link or not? I don't want to open any connection or network operation I just to want to check the pattern of string is matching to the pattern of a link or not.
e.g

```swift
    let str1 = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask" // It is a link
    let str2 = "https://stackoverflow.com" // It is a link
     // Could be other combinations as well of a valid link 
    let str3 = "this is not a link" // Not a link
```

How to do that? Is It possible to check with regular expression or any other way or not possible?

Comment: yes but how to apply this in swift ? Can you explain it ?thanks

Comment: also this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28079123/how-to-check-validity-of-url-in-swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the check with URL initializer that returns optional value. Example

```
let str1 = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"
if let url = URL.init(string: str1) {
        // It will pass            
}

let str2 = "not a link"
if let url = URL.init(string: str2) {
        // It will not pass            
}
```

You can do exactly the same with `guard let - else { }`

Comment: This is not passing for "not a link" but passing for "notalink" which is not a link.

Comment: Dosei penalty to OFI