# Correct way to handle incorrect URL when opening

Tags: ios, swift, url

The task is quite simple. With a given `urlString` open it when it is valid. This is what I tried:

```
func openURL(_ urlString: String) {
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        showInvalidUrlAlert()
        return
    }
    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
}
```

This work with this example: "https://www.google.de/?hl=de"

However when passing an invalid url, which is also possible in my application (for example: "asdfd") I get this error on the console but nothing happens in the app:

> [default] Failed to open URL asdf: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "invalid input parameters" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=invalid input parameters, _LSLine=252, _LSFunction=-[_LSDOpenClient openURL:options:completionHandler:]}

What is the *best practice* here?

Comment: Even `www.google.com` is failing here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use the `completionHandler` parameter:

```
func openURL(_ urlString: String) {
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        showInvalidUrlAlert()
        return
    }
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, completionHandler: { success in
        if success {
            print("opened")
        } else {
            print("failed")
            // showInvalidUrlAlert()
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: thanks, do I have to handle the `success` case somehow?

Comment: @Chris No, you can easily do `if !success { showInvalidUrlAlert() }`

Comment: @Chris But this is another question and your edit changes the whole context. I'd suggest you remove your edit and post as a new question. I'll try to help you there.

Comment: done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63102385/handle-completion-if-no-success-when-opening-url-with-safariviewcontroller

Answer (score 3):

Did the URL have a `http` or `https` scheme attached? to open a website, you must require the `String` to have http(s). other wise the application won't know how to handle it, since it also handles other protocols.

> ...supports many common schemes, including the http, https, tel, facetime, and mailto schemes...

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1648685-open

Answer (score 1):

Inside of `guard` statement, you can `throw` an exception created by your application instead only put a `return`, like this:

```
guard let urlString = url, !urlString.isEmpty, let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
    throw ErrorEnum.invalidURL
}
```

With this approach, you can catch the error and send a UI Feedback for the User where it calls de func `openURL`.

Comment: but I am already sending back a feedback with `showInvalidUrlAlert` but thats not called with the example above..

Comment: Is because is creating de `url` with the string `asdfd`, in this case, is falling in the moment to open for the App `UIApplication.shared.open(url)` ... is ugly, I know but the API is building de URL even is not a valid URL.

Comment: So Whats the way to Go Here?

Comment: You can create an extension for URL ... `extension URL: ExpressibleByStringLiteral`, like this approach here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-make-custom-types-from-strings-using-expressiblebystringliteral, take a look.

Comment: Maybe this thread can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28079123/how-to-check-validity-of-url-in-swift