# Handle completion if no success when opening url with SafariViewController

Tags: ios, swift, completionhandler, sfsafariviewcontroller

Is there a way to handle the case if `SafariViewController` fails to open a `url` like you can with `UIApplication.shared.open`?
This is my function:

```
if ["http", "https"].contains(url.scheme?.lowercased() ?? "") {
    // Can open with SFSafariViewController
    let safariViewController = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
    self.present(safariViewController, animated: true) {
        // no bool given?
    }
} else {
    // Scheme is not supported or no scheme is given, use openURL
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        self.showInvalidUrlAlert()
        return
    }
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, completionHandler: { success in
        if !success {
            print("failed")
            self.showInvalidUrlAlert()
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `SFSafariViewController` provides much interaction/feedback with your app.

As per Apple documentation:

> The user's activity and interaction with SFSafariViewController are
> not visible to your app, which cannot access AutoFill data, browsing
> history, or website data.

> Choosing the Best Web Viewing Class
>
> If your app lets users view
> websites from anywhere on the Internet, use the SFSafariViewController
> class. If your app customizes, interacts with, or controls the display
> of web content, use the WKWebView class.

As Apple suggests, you may want to take a look at [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview) class.

Answer (score 1):

Make your presenter view controller to conform `SFSafariViewControllerDelegate`.

```
class ViewController: SFSafariViewControllerDelegate
```

and set `ViewController` as delegate of `SafariViewController`

```
safariViewController.delegate = self
```

Then handle load status whether it is successful using
[didCompleteInitialLoad](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontrollerdelegate/1621215-safariviewcontroller) delegate.

```
func safariViewController(_ controller: SFSafariViewController, didCompleteInitialLoad didLoadSuccessfully: Bool) {
    // Handle loadStatus. 
    print(didLoadSuccessfully)

    // if load unsuccessful, dismiss SFSafariViewController and try to open using openURL
    if !didLoadSuccessfully {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true) {
            // UIApplication.shared.open(..               
        }
    }
}
```